# Keep session or refresh cookieManager in Oauth2 authentication

Tags: android, cookies, oauth-2.0, token, session-cookies

In my app I am using rest api to get json object for users and information. The authentication system is Oauth2. At first to use the app, user need to write their email address and password. and if the user existing email and pasword in web, they can succesfully login and see all the information. Now, I used cookiemanager to keep and pass the cookie to use that in other rest api. I am very new in handligh that situation. THe problem is the cookie is not refreshed with username and password. I would like to keep the session forever by refreshing the coockie each time. But do not now how can I do that. I am explaining with the following code

The login code where user give username and password. I used Volley Library. and the method is POST.

```
public class LoginPage extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs";

public static final String LOGIN_URL = "url_of_my_app";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "username";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String KEY_IS_USER_LOGED_IN = "is-user-logged-in";


private String mEmail;
private String mPassword;

public static CookieManager cookieManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    //login credential

    mEmail = sharedpreferences.getString(KEY_EMAIL, null);
    mPassword = sharedpreferences.getString(KEY_PASSWORD, null);

    if (mEmail != null && mPassword != null && sharedpreferences.getBoolean(KEY_IS_USER_LOGED_IN, false)) {

        final GlobalClass globalClass = new GlobalClass();
        globalClass.setEmail_info(mEmail);

        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(LoginPage.this, MainOptionPage.class);
        loginIntent.putExtra(KEY_EMAIL, mEmail);
        startActivity(loginIntent);
        finish();

    } else {


        });


    }
}


private void attemptLogin() {

   ...
}



//volley library to hit the request

private void loginUser(final String mEmail, final String mPassword) {

    final GlobalClass globalClass = new GlobalClass();
    globalClass.setEmail_info(mEmail);

    setFilePath();

    this.trustAllCertificates();

    cookieManager = new CookieManager(new PersistentCookieStore(getApplicationContext()), CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);

    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginPage.this);
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            LOGIN_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Register Response: " + response.toString());

            //parse your response here
            if (response.contains("overview")) {
                showProgress(true);

                if (!globalClass.ifUserDataExist(mEmail)) {
                    Log.d("----After Login---", "After Login");
                   ....
                }

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putString(KEY_EMAIL, mEmail);
                editor.putString(KEY_PASSWORD, mPassword);
                editor.putBoolean(KEY_IS_USER_LOGED_IN, true);

                editor.commit();


                loginIntent.putExtra(KEY_EMAIL, mEmail);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
                finish();

            } else {
                userEmail.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_login));
                userEmail.requestFocus();

            }
        }

    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Log.e(TAG, "Inside getParams");
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(KEY_EMAIL, mEmail);
            Log.d("email address", mEmail);
            params.put(KEY_PASSWORD, mPassword);
            return params;
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            Log.d("headers", String.valueOf(headers));
            return headers;
        }

    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    queue.add(strReq);
}
```

Now in UserActivity I am getting user information from Rest API if the login is successful. Hence I am getting those information. Bur after a certain time the session is expires and the recyclerview is blank.

I am giving only the Volley part of this activity class. I have used a alett dialog if the cookie is null. But in practise I do not want to do this. How can I keep the login credential forever which give me access to use all the api all the time.

```
 public void sendRequest() {

    trustAllCertificates();

    CookieHandler.setDefault( cookieManager );

    if (cookieManager==null) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Your session has expired");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //dialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent( MyColleaguesPage.this, LoginPage.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                //editor.remove("username");
                //editor.remove("password");
                editor.remove(LoginPage.KEY_IS_USER_LOGED_IN);
                editor.apply();
                finish();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    } else {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest( Request.Method.GET, UPLOAD_URL + "/api/users", null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                    MyColleagueModel mycolleague = new MyColleagueModel();

                    try {
                        JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject( i );

                        mycolleague.setName( object.optString( "name" ) );
                        mycolleague.setGivenName( object.optString( "givenName" ) );
                        mycolleague.setCompany( object.optString( "company" ) );
                        mycolleague.setTitle( object.optString( "title" ) );
                        mycolleague.setMail( object.optString( "mail" ) );
                        mycolleague.setMobile( object.optString( "mobile" ) );
                        mycolleague.setDepartment( object.optString( "department" ) );

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    myColleagueList.add( mycolleague );

                }

                adapter = new MyColleaguesAdapter( myColleagueList, MyColleaguesPage.this );

                recyclerView.setAdapter( adapter );

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i( "Volley Error: ", error.toString() );
            }
        } );

        rq.add( jsonArrayRequest );
    }
}
```

Comment: The time an auth token/cookie is valid for is dependent on the authentication service. Does the OAuth service expose a refresh token?

Comment: @Anth12 is that possible to keep session with username and password. Sorry I could not understand your question

Comment: If your authentication server supports refersh tokens (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-1.5) you can use them to obtain a new access token once it expires. Access tokens are generated by the authentication server and their lifetime is defined by the auth server.

Comment: @Anth12 How can I know that the server supports refresh token. is there any way to get that when I have logged in. Sorry I am very new in this case

Comment: You can check your auth server documentation or review the response from the authorization request to confirm a `refresh` token is supplied by the server.